# count($array) returning wrong array length

Tags: php, arrays, permutation

I'm trying to write a program, that prints every possible permutation of array elements.

Example: `listPermutations($array)`, where `$array = array(0,1,2)` should return the six permutations `0,1,2` `0,2,1` `1,0,2`, `1,2,0`, `2,0,1`, `2,1,0`.

The code I have so far is:

```
<?php

    $myNumber = 3;

    function createArray($objCount){
        for($i = 0; $i < $objCount; $i++){
            $array[$i] = $i;
        }
        return $array;
    }

    function printPermutations($array, $firstObj){
        //echo var_dump($array)."<br>";
        echo count($array)."<br>";
        if(count($array) == 2){
            echo $firstObj.$array[0].$array[1];
            echo $firstObj.$array[1].$array[0];
        }
        else{
            for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
                $arrayWithoutI = array_splice($array, $i, 1);
                echo var_dump($array)."<br>";
                echo printPermutations($arrayWithoutI, $i).' ';
            }
        }
    }

    function listPermutations($objCount){
        $array = createArray($objCount);
        //echo print_r($array)."<br>";
        printPermutations($array, 0);
    }

    echo listPermutations($myNumber);
?>
```

The code should work recursively as follows:

If the array length of `$array` is not equal to two, then for each element `$i` in the array call `printPermutaions` with `$i` removed and with `$i` as the
first element of the permutation.

However the output of the program is as follows:

```
3
array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) } 
1
array(0) { } 
1
array(0) { } 
1
array(0) { } 
1
array(0) { } 
1 ...
...
```

Why would the output after removing one element be 1 instead of 2?

Comment: `echo var_dump($array)` You print the return value of `var_dump()`, which is just unnecessary. Same for `echo printPermutations(...)` which also doesn't print anything.

Comment: that is true, but that is only for testing purposes.

Comment: @Alex What Rizier123 is saying is that you don't need `echo` at all. `var_dump()` prints a value but *returns* nothing, so using `echo` is completely redundant.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks for the the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

array splice gets the array by reference

```
array array_splice( array &$input , int $offset [, int $length [, mixed $replacement = array() ]] )
```

means it is changing the given array.
when you iterate from 0 to `count($array)` it counts the array length every loop run.

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
count($array); //5
array_splice($array,2);
count($array); //2
```

array_splice changes the array length. and count($array) changes.

Comment: so since array_splice gets an array array by reference, would you suggest to make temporary copies of these arrays or is there a call-by-value alternative?

Comment: that is also an option, i'm not sure that if you write `$clonedArray = $array` it clones it (and not just giving it same pointer). here's a way to clone an array for sure: `$clonedArray = json_decode(json_encode($array));`, notice that if one of your values in the array is not serializable (like function, or some special object) it will ignore the value